# rails 3 & mysql2 installation on XP

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to install rails 3 on windows XP with mysql.rails 3 install straight but during mysql2 installation it gives Native Error Exception. If some one install rails 3 with mysql2 on windows XP please show the installation steps.

Error Like this....

```
D:\ROR\InstantRails\rails_apps>gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/bin/ruby
D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:435:in `try_link0'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:440:in `try_link'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_func'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:797:in `block in have_func'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:796:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.4 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.4/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out

D:\ROR\InstantRails\rails_apps>gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/bin/ruby
D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:435:in `try_link0'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:440:in `try_link'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_func'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:797:in `block in have_func'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
        from D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:796:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.4 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/ROR/InstantRails/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.4/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: If you could give some detail on what's not working, like a copy-paste of an error message or stack trace, this would make it a lot easier to answer. Right now there's barely anything specific to address.

Comment: tadman thanks for suggestion ,here i write whole error please look it

Answer (score 1):

If anybody still facing problem of installing mysql2 gem with rails 3 on Windows, then refer to the detailed steps of installation on -
http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html

Comment: This is old now. It is Ruby 1.9.2. It doesn't work for 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

mysql2 is still *nix-only, they a ticket to provide windows version of the gem.